# Getting Device Pitch of Android Device in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, angle

Is there any library that gives pitch(One of the device tilt angle) information in React-Native?

Found [Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-angles) but is only for IOS.

Do we have any similar ones for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [React Native Sensors](https://github.com/react-native-sensors/react-native-sensors) library is useful to only get info of Accelerometer and Gyroscope.

However, it doesn't provide any information about calculating the pitch, roll and yaw of the device like how [Native Android Development](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager#getOrientation(float[],%20float[])) does.

There exists another react-native library [React Native Sensor Manager](https://github.com/kprimice/react-native-sensor-managerhttp://), which provides orientation data and also access to other sensors data such as Step Detector and Proximity Sensor

Answer (score 2):

This [react native library](https://github.com/react-native-sensors/react-native-sensors) to get native sensors information can support what you need

Answer (score 0):

The library [React Native Sensors](https://github.com/react-native-sensors/react-native-sensors) is now providing pitch measuring feature (orientation).

Make sure you have the '**react-native-sensors**' library installed and properly configured in your React Native project to utilize this feature.
You may want to take a look to the [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-sensors/react-native-sensors/blob/master/docs/API.md#orientation-observableqx-number-qy-number-qz-number-qw-number-pitch-number-roll-number-yaw-number-timestamp-string)!.

```
const subscription = orientation.subscribe(({ qx, qy, qz, qw, pitch, roll, yaw, timestamp }) =>
  console.log({ qx, qy, qz, qw, pitch, roll, yaw, timestamp })
);
```